# test is not executed - nightwatch with standard mocha and phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, mocha.js, nightwatch.js

so i have a nodejs server and I want to start on some functional tests with nightwatch.

If I start selenium manually and I run it with mocha ( command: mocha ./test/functional/*.spec.js --compilers js:babel-register) it starts the node server and runs fine in firefox(default - by the way using standard mocha how can it be changed from default firefox to other browser?):

```
import nightwatch from 'nightwatch';

require('../../server');

describe('Functional', function wrapIt() {
  const client = nightwatch.initClient({
    silent: true,
  });

  const browser = client.api();

  this.timeout(99999999);

  beforeEach((done) => {
    client.start(done);
  });

  it('should login', (done) => {
    browser
      .url('http://localhost:8441/')
      .waitForElementVisible('button[name=login]', 1000)
      .click('button[name=login]')
      .pause(1000);

    browser.expect.element('button').to.have.attribute('class').which.contains('theme__button');
    browser.end();
    client.start(done);
  });

  after((done) => {
    browser.end();
    client.start(done);
  });
});
```

Now i want to put it on Bamboo and use phantomjs, selenium server starts, nodejs server starts but the test is not executed.
I have **nightwatch.json**:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["test/night"],
  "output_folder": "reports",
  "test_runner" : "mocha",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": ".//bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar",
    "log_path": "./reports",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4444
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "phantomjs",
        "phantomjs.cli.args" : ["--ignore-ssl-errors=true"],
        "version":"latest",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

,**nightwatch.conf.js** is:

```
require('babel-core/register');

module.exports = require('./nightwatch.json');
```

and the test script in night folder:

```
require('../../server');

describe('Functional', function wrapIt() {
  const client = this.client;
  const browser = client.api();

  this.timeout(99999999);

  beforeEach((done) => {
    client.start(done);
  });

  it('should login', (done) => {
    browser
      .url('http://localhost:8441/')
      .waitForElementVisible('button[name=login]', 1000)
      .click('button[name=login]')
      .pause(1000);

    browser.expect.element('button').to.have.attribute('class').which.contains('theme__button');
    browser.end();
    client.start(done);
  });

  after((done) => {
    browser.end();
    client.start(done);
  });
});
```

So running it with nightwatch it starts the selenium server, also the nodejs server starts ok but then nothing happens.

Comment: Is that selenium server path right? Also, do you have the logs from Bamboo? They may help point you to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it using webdriver:

```
export const client = require('webdriverjs').remote({ // eslint-disable-line
  // Settings
  desiredCapabilities: {
    // You may choose other browsers
    // http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities
    browserName: 'phantomjs',
  },
  // webdriverjs has a lot of output which is generally useless
  // However, if anything goes wrong, remove this to see more details
  logLevel: 'silent',
});

client.init();
```

and:

```
require('../../server');

const client = require('./client').client;

describe('Functional testing', function wrapIt() {
  this.timeout(99999999);

  before((done) => {
    client.init().url('http://localhost:8441/', done);
  });

  describe('Check homepage', () => {
    it('should login', (done) => {
      client.waitFor('button[name=login]', 100, () => {
        client.click('button[name=login]', () => {
          client.element('.theme__button*');
          client.waitForVisible(1000);
          client.end();
        });
      });
      done();
    });
  });

  after((done) => {
    client.end();
    done();
  });
});
```

and it works running mocha './test/funcTest.js' --compilers js:babel-register -t 10000

PS: selenium is already started local and on bamboo I added a commmand to start it